# Problemas com number format - Adicionando caracteres

Tags: php

Quero retornar um valor de uma variável, só que quando eu insiro a função number_format na variável, acaba adicionando 2 zeros no fim do valor

```
$valor = 5300000; // Aqui o número só está sem a formatação | aqui só adicionaria a virgula e o ponto e ficaria: 53,000.00
$valor_f = number_format($valor, 2, ",", ".");
```

Ele está me retornando 5,300,000,00, eu gostaria que retornasse 53,000.00.

Comment: Se você precisa converter o número 5 milhões e 300 para 53 ml não é apenas com formatação que você conseguirá. Você precisará dividir por 100 antes.

Comment: De qualquer forma, se você tira o caractere de separação decimal de um número você obterá outro valor. Se precisa desfazer o processo, terá que fazer a divisão. O problema está em `3.14159`, valor de pi; se você remover a formatação ficará `314159`. Como saberá quantas casas decimais o número precisa ter?

Answer (score 3):

Se você precisa mudar o número "cinco milhões e trezentos mil" no número "cinquenta e três mil" obviamente que não será apenas formatando, pois são valores diferentes.

Nesse caso bem específico basta você dividir por 100:

```
$valor_f = number_format($valor/100, 2, ",", ".");  // 53,000.00
```

Mas não garanto que isso funcionará para todos os casos que precisa pois é bastante incomum querer obter outro valor a partir da formatação.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por etapas.
1º converta um inteiro para float:

```
$valor = sprintf("%.2f", 5300000);
```

2º coloque o number_format:

```
$valor_f = number_format($valor, 2, ",", ".");
```

Note que dessa maneira, você pode substituir o 5300000 por qualquer outro número.

Comment: Agora me retorna: "5,300,000"

Comment: Eu testei foi normal para mim. Achei que o 5300000 eram inteiros, se no caso você quer pegar os dois ultimos zeros e transformar em decimal, use a dica do Anderson.